# Upload libreoffice impress presentation to youtube?

Tags: libreoffice

I am interested in creating a presentation in Libreoffice Impress, exporting in X format, and uploading it to Youtube with little hassle.

How do I do this? What should X be? And have you done this successfully before?

Comment: Hm, good question. I know you can export a PowerPoint presentation as a video. Is that essentially what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, Powerpoint apparently has popular method(s) for this. Let's see what LibreOffice offers.

Answer (score 0):

Convert odp to swf using LibreOffice Impress.

1. Launch LibreOffice Impress.
2. File -> Open, open the .odp presentation that you wish to convert to flash.
3. Click File -> Export.
4. Choose Adobe Flash (SWF) (.swf) in the Filter box. Click OK.

Cons: All the animations, multimedia files in the presentation will disappear after conversion.

Comment: What about the timing of the presentation; will it be any faster or slower in Youtube? I read comments alluding to that, and want to know if you have experience in this. Thanks.

Comment: There is a problem. Youtube does NOT accept .swf files for posting. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

follow my basic understanding

from youtube help forum

"I created an open office presentation and i want to upload it to my channel.  .odp is not a supported file however, and when i went to the supported youtube file formats page .odp was not there.  it was not even mentioned on the page, even under the others section.  how can i upload the presentation?  The link to the presentation is in the descripion."

https://www.online-convert.com/

which you can do straight from pdf or odp to mp4 but better straight from odp